# Message not showing up in my react native chat bot

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I'm making a chat bot app in react native and I am facing some difficulty in showing the messages that are saved in my firebase. The message box shows up empty. Moreover, three messages show up whereas there is only one message in my firebase. I am using React-Redux for state management and react-native-router-flux for navigation

Here is the code of my Login.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar, ImageBackground} from 'react-native'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {login, loginUser} from '../actions'
import {Input, Card, Button, Spinner} from './common'

class Login extends Component {
    loginUser() {
        const {email, password} = this.props
        this.props.loginUser({email, password})
    }

    renderButton() {
        if(this.props.loading) {
            return <Spinner size='large' />
        }

        return (
            <Button style={{backgroundColor: '#2D99FC', color: 'white'}}
                text='Sign in'
                onPress={this.loginUser.bind(this)}
            />
        )
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ImageBackground
                style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
                source={require('../assets/images/bg.jpg')}
            >
                <StatusBar hidden />
                <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 25, fontWeight: 'bold', margin: 10}}>Login</Text>
                    <Text style={{color: 'grey', margin: 10}}>Stay Connected</Text>

                    <Card>
                        <Input
                            placeholder='name@example.com'
                            iconName='user'
                            value={this.props.email}
                            onChangeText={value => this.props.login({prop: 'email', value})}
                        />
                        <Input
                            placeholder="******"
                            iconName='lock'
                            secureTextEntry
                            value={this.props.password}
                            onChangeText={value => this.props.login({prop: 'password', value})}
                        />

                        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'red'}}>
                            {this.props.error}
                        </Text>

                        {this.renderButton()}

                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text style={{color:'#2D99FC', fontWeight: 'bold', margin: 10, marginBottom: 30}}>Forgot Password?</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', margin: 10}}>
                            <Text>Don't have an account? </Text>
                            <TouchableOpacity>
                                <Text style={{color:'#2D99FC', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Sign Up</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </Card>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const {email, password, loading, error} = state.auth
    return {email, password, loading, error}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {login, loginUser})(Login)
```

Here is my code of AuthAction.js:

```
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux'
import User from '../User'
import {REGISTER, SIGN_UP_USER, SIGN_UP_USER_SUCCESS, SIGN_UP_USER_FAIL, LOGIN, LOGIN_USER, LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, LOGIN_USER_FAIL, UPDATE_USERS} from './types'

export const register = ({prop, value}) => {
    return {
        type: REGISTER,
        payload: {prop, value}
    }
}

export const createUser = ({email, password, conPass, name}) => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: SIGN_UP_USER})

        if(password !== conPass) {
            signupUserFail(dispatch, 'Passwords do not match')
        }
        else {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(user => {
                    signupUserSuccess(dispatch, user)
                    addData(name, email)
                })
                .catch(() => signupUserFail(dispatch, 'Authentication Failed'))
        }
    }
}

const addData = async (name, email) => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('userName', name)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('userEmail', email)
    User.name = name
    User.email = email
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + User.name).set({name, email})
}

const signupUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
    dispatch({
        type: SIGN_UP_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user
    })
}

const signupUserFail = (dispatch, error) => {
    dispatch({
        type: SIGN_UP_USER_FAIL,
        payload: error
    })
}

export const login = ({prop, value}) => {
    return {
        type: LOGIN,
        payload: {prop, value}
    }
}

export const loginUser = ({email, password}) => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: LOGIN_USER})


        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(user => loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user))
            .catch(() => loginUserFail(dispatch, 'Authentication Failed'))
    }
}

const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user
    })

    firebase.database().ref('users')
        .on('child_added', (val) => {
            let person = val.val()
            person.name = val.key
            dispatch({type: UPDATE_USERS, payload: person})
        })
    Actions.chat()
}

const loginUserFail = (dispatch, error) => {
    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_FAIL,
        payload: error
    })
}
```

Here is my code to AuthReducer.js:

```
import {REGISTER, SIGN_UP_USER, SIGN_UP_USER_SUCCESS, SIGN_UP_USER_FAIL, LOGIN, LOGIN_USER, LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS, LOGIN_USER_FAIL, UPDATE_USERS} from '../actions/types'
import User from '../User'

const INITIAL_STATE = {email: '', password: '', conPass: '', loading: false, error: '', user: null, name: '', user: []}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    console.log(action)
    switch(action.type) {
        //Registration
        case REGISTER:
            return {...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value}
        case SIGN_UP_USER:
            return {...state, loading: true, error: ''}
        case SIGN_UP_USER_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, ...INITIAL_STATE, user: action.payload}
        case SIGN_UP_USER_FAIL:
            return {...state, error: action.payload, password: '', conPass: '', loading: false}

        //Login
        case LOGIN:
            return {...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value}
        case LOGIN_USER:
            return {...state, loading: true, error: ''}
        case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
            return {...state, ...INITIAL_STATE, user: action.payload}
        case LOGIN_USER_FAIL:
            return {...state, error: action.payload, password: '', loading: false}
        case UPDATE_USERS:
            User.name = action.payload.name
            User.email = action.payload.email

        //default
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Here is my code to Chat.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, SafeAreaView, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar, Dimensions, FlatList} from 'react-native'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {messageChanged, sendMessage, messagesListFetch} from '../actions'
import { Header } from './common';
import User from '../User';

class Chat extends Component {
    onMessageChange(text) {
        this.props.messageChanged(text)
    }

    sendMessage() {
        const {message} = this.props
        this.props.sendMessage(message)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.messagesListFetch()
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <View>
                    <StatusBar hidden />
                    <Header text='Chat with Me' />
                </View>
                <SafeAreaView>
                    <FlatList
                        scrollEnabled
                        style={{padding: 10, height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.8}}
                        data={this.props.messageList}
                        renderItem={(item) => {
                            return(
                                <View style={{
                                    flexDirection: 'row',
                                    width: '60%',
                                    alignSelf: item[0] === User.name ? 'flex-end' : 'flex-start',
                                    backgroundColor: item[0] === User.name ? '#00897B' : '#7CB342',                                    
                                    borderRadius: 5,
                                    marginBottom: 10
                                }}>
                                    <Text style={{color: '#FFF', padding: 7, fontSize: 16}}>{item[1]}</Text>
                                    <Text style={{color: '#EEE', padding: 3, fontSize: 12}}>{item[2]}</Text>
                                </View>
                            )
                        }}
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item[0]}
                    />

                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginHorizontal: 5}}>
                        <TextInput
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder='Type a message...'
                            value={this.props.message}
                            onChangeText={this.onMessageChange.bind(this)}
                        />

                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.sendMessage.bind(this)} style={{paddingBottom: 10, marginLeft: 5}}>
                            <Text>Send</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </SafeAreaView>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    input: {
        padding: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        width: '80%',
        marginBottom: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    let messages = state.chat.messageList
    let messageList = []
    Object.keys(messages).map((key, index) => {
        messageList.push(messages[key])
    })
    let message = state.chat.message

    return {message, messageList}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {messageChanged, sendMessage, messagesListFetch})(Chat)
```

Here is my code to ChatActions.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import {MESSAGE_CHANGED, MESSAGE_SENT, GET_MESSAGE_LIST} from './types'
import User from '../User'

export const messageChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: MESSAGE_CHANGED,
        payload: text
    }
}

export const sendMessage = (textMessage) => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        if(textMessage.length > 0) {
            console.log(User.name)
            let msgId = firebase.database().ref('messages').child(User.name).child('Bot').push().key
            let updates = {}
            let message = {
                message: textMessage,
                time: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                from: User.name
            }
            updates['messages/' + User.name + '/' + 'Bot' + '/' + msgId] = message
            updates['messages/' + 'Bot' + '/' + User.name + '/' + msgId] = message
            firebase.database().ref().update(updates)
            dispatch({type: MESSAGE_SENT})
        }
    }
}

export const messagesListFetch = () => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            firebase.database().ref('messages').child(User.name).child('Bot')
                .on('child_added', (value) => {
                    dispatch({type: GET_MESSAGE_LIST, payload: value.val()})
                    // console.log(value.val())
            })
        }, 1000)
    }
}
```

Here is my code to ChatReducer.js:

```
import {MESSAGE_CHANGED, MESSAGE_SENT, GET_MESSAGE_LIST} from '../actions/types'

const INITIAl_STATE = {message: '', messageList: []}

export default (state = INITIAl_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case MESSAGE_CHANGED:
            return {...state, message: action.payload}
        case MESSAGE_SENT:
            return {...state, message: ''}
        case GET_MESSAGE_LIST:
            return {...state, messageList: action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}


Here is my User.js:

User = {
    name: '',
    email: ''
}

export default User
```

I want the message to show, and to show only once, not thrice. How can I do that? Can anyone help me here?